# iOS: What changes App Tracking Transparency implies to Adjust/FB/Firebase SDKs?

Tags: ios, analytics, apptrackingtransparency

So far my app was using Adjust, FB and Firebase SDKs for Analytics purposes. So my `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method was roughly looking like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Adjust
    let adjustConfig = ADJConfig(appToken: ADJ_TOKEN, environment: ADJ_ENV)
    Adjust.appDidLaunch(adjustConfig)
    // FB 
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
                                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
    }
    // Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Other initializations...
    return true
}
```

With the addition of the `AppTrackingTransparency` framework, I am now displaying a popup to the users at launch:

```
// Before return true in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
requestTrackingPermission()

func requestTrackingPermission() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                break
            case .denied:
                break
            case .notDetermined:
                break
            case .restricted:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused, however, about what to do next: do I need to move the Analytics initialization lines in the `.authorized` case of the tracking permission request? What should I do for the denied/restricted cases? And in what situation may the case be not determined?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link to understand more about Firebase and Apple's App Tracking Transparency framework

[Supporting iOS 14](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14)